# Compiling in Modelsim VHDL

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, modelsim

I tried to run a VHDL code but this error (vcom-11) keeps coming out.

> vcom -work work -2002 -explicit -vopt -stats=none /nas/ei/home/ga94mel/Documents/VHDL_C/test_bench.vhd
>   Model Technology ModelSim SE-64 vcom 10.4c Compiler 2015.07 Jul 19 2015
>
> -- Loading package STANDARD
>
> -- Loading package TEXTIO
>
> -- Loading package std_logic_1164
>
> -- Loading package NUMERIC_STD
>
> -- Compiling entity MEM4096x12TEST
>
> -- Compiling configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF
>
> ** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.mem4096x12test(TB).
>
> ** Error: /nas/ei/home/ga94mel/Documents/VHDL_C/test_bench.vhd(10): (vcom-1537) Block specification "TB" is not an architecture name.
>
> ** Error: /nas/ei/home/ga94mel/Documents/VHDL_C/test_bench.vhd(11): VHDL Compiler exiting

Here is the script:

```
    LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
    ENTITY MEM4096x12TEST IS
    end  MEM4096x12TEST ;

    --Configuration for Component Instantiation 

    configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF of MEM4096x12TEST is
    for TB
     for UUT: MEM4096x12 use 
        entity WORK.RAM4096x12(behavioral)
         port map(
          w_en => w_en_C,
          addr => addr_C,
          data_in => data_in_C,
          data_out => data_out_C);
      end for;
    end for;
    end MEM4096x12TESTCONF; 

    architecture TB  of MEM4096x12TEST IS 
    Component MEM4096x12  
    PORT(
    w_en_C : in bit;
    addr_C : in bit_vector(11 downto 0);
    data_in_C: in bit_vector(11 downto 0);
    data_out_C: out  bit_vector (11 downto 0)
    );
    end Component ;
    Signal w_en_s :bit :='0';
    Signal addr_s, data_in_s, data_out_s  :  bit_vector(11 downto 0);
    begin 
    UUT: MEM4096x12 
    Port Map (w_en_C => w_en_s, 
        addr_C => addr_s,
        data_in_C => data_in_s , 
        data_out_C => data_out_s );
    w_en_s <= '1' after 5ns , '0' after 10 ns ; 
    data_in_s <="111111111111"  after 4 ns ; 
    addr_s <="000000000001"  after 4 ns , 
             "000000000010"  after 12 ns , 
             "000000000001"  after 20 ns ; 
    end TB ;

--Configuration for Entity Instantiation

configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF of MEM4096x12TEST is
for TB
end For ; 
end MEM4096x12TESTCONF ;

architecture TB of MEM4096x12TEST_short IS 
Signal w_en_s :bit ; 
Signal addr_s,data_in_s , data_out_s  :  bit_vector(11 downto 0); 
begin 
UUT : entity Work.MEM4096x12(behavioral) 
port map ( w_en => w_en_s,
    addr => addr_s,
    data_in => data_in_s , 
    data_out => data_out_s); 
w_en_s <= '1' after 5ns , '0' after 10 ns ; 
data_in_s <= "111111111111"  after 4 ns ; 
addr_s <= "000000000001"  after 4 ns , 
          "000000000010"  after 12 ns , 
          "000000000001"  after 20 ns ; 
end TB ;
```

Comment: Configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF needs to go after the architecture.

Comment: Configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF appears twice.

Comment: There is no entity for MEM4096x12TEST_short.

Comment: `** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.mem4096x12test(TB).  ** Error: /nas/ei/home/ga94mel/Documents/VHDL_C/test_bench.vhd(10): (vcom-1537) Block specification "TB" is not an architecture name.` Your component specification in  configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF is in error.. MEM4096x12 isn't a component name (declared in a component declaration) made visible in any specified reference library or the block declarative part  (architecture) of MEM4096x12TEST. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.3 Configuration specification, 12.2 Scope of declarations para 4.

Comment: The simplest thing you could do is remove (comment out) the first and second configuration declaration. Configuration declarations are not strictly necessary in VHDL where there is a default binding indication (7.3.2 Binding indication, 7.3.3 Default binding indication).  Otherwise there's an analysis order issue where the architecture TB of MEM4096x12 hasn't made the component declaration visible by analysis prior to analyzing MEM4096x12TESTCONF (paragraph 4 of 12.2 Scope of declarations). This appears to be all one design file move the configuration declaration after the architecture.

Comment: The default binding indication is the equivalent of the second configuration declaration which will replace the first. There's also no entity declaration for MEM4096x12TEST_short. nor is MEM4096x12 found.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration MEM4096x12TESTCONF needs to go after the architecture.